# VBA code to search for files from our server and route users to specific folder locations based on their button selection

Tags: vba

I am a beginner in VBA, trying different methods. I found this code on the net, but it gives me an object error. Doesn't quite accomplish what i have in mind

```
Sub FindMaster() 
    Dim wbResults As Workbook 

    With Application.FileSearch 
        .NewSearch 
        .LookIn = "C:\" 
        .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks 
        .Filename = "Master.xls" 
        If .Execute > 0 Then 'Workbooks in folder
            Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(lCount), UpdateLinks:=0) 
        Else 
            MsgBox "Not found" 
        End If 
    End With
```

Is there a better way to search for files via a userform drop down list, but first the code must detect if the user has folder access or not then route the user to the specific file or folder

Thanks

Comment: `Application.FileSearch` was removed in Excel 2007.  See: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/643288-excel-2010-visual-basic-applications-replacement-application-filesearch.html